# How to 'console.log' data from response

Tags: typescript, angular

I have service that return some data:

```
return this._http.get(`api/data`)
    .map((response: Response) => response.json());
```

How can I `console.log(response.json())` or is there any better ways to inspect resonse?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
return this._http.get(`api/data`)
  .map((response: Response) => {
    var result = response.json();
    console.log(result);
    return result;
   });
```

or better

```
return this._http.get(`api/data`)
    .map((response: Response) => response.json())
    .do(value => console.log(value));
```

Ensure you have imported the operators you use.

Comment: oh I was trying `.then` but that is promises way which is didnt work so now I see that I have to use `.do`. Have to learn more about observables..